# Replicate a row as many times to a dataframe when one specific value in the row is matched

Tags: r, dataframe, replication

I have a data frame that looks like

```
Age    Sex    Height    Weight   Status    obesity  
17      m      5.6      36.3     single    Normal  
30      f      4.5      80.5     married   Abnormal
31      f      5.5      60.7     single    Normal
35      m      4.9      110.9    single    Very Abnormal
```

And I want something like

```
Age    Sex    Height    Weight   Status    obesity  
17      m      5.6      36.3     single    Normal  
30      f      4.5      80.5     married   Abnormal
31      f      5.5      60.7     single    Normal
35      m      4.9      110.9    single    Very Abnormal
30      f      4.5      80.5     married   Abnormal
30      f      4.5      80.5     married   Abnormal
30      f      4.5      80.5     married   Abnormal
30      f      4.5      80.5     married   Abnormal
30      f      4.5      80.5     married   Abnormal
35      m      4.9      110.9    single    Very Abnormal
35      m      4.9      110.9    single    Very Abnormal
35      m      4.9      110.9    single    Very Abnormal
35      m      4.9      110.9    single    Very Abnormal
35      m      4.9      110.9    single    Very Abnormal
35      m      4.9      110.9    single    Very Abnormal
```

To replicate a row of the data frame, a certain criteria must be met in a specific column or one of the values of the row as shown, e.g. `obesity == Abnormal`. Then the values of the row need to be replicated the given number of times. The replication can be as many as possible, e.g. 1000.

Comment: You can use `df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$specificcolumn),]`

Comment: Thanks. But what of if replication is based on condition say obesity==Abnormal. Then replicate it like 1000 times.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general solution which might be somewhat over the top. The idea is to set up a table with conditions or rules to identify the rows and the number of repetitions:

```
library(data.table)
rows_to_repeat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~rule,    ~n_rep,
  "obesity == 'Abnormal'",      5,
  "obesity == 'Very Abnormal'", 6,
  "Age > 30",                   2
  )
setDT(rows_to_repeat)[]
```

> ```
>                          rule n_rep
> 1:      obesity == 'Abnormal'     5
> 2: obesity == 'Very Abnormal'     6
> 3:                   Age > 30     2
> ```

Then, we loop over the rules, pick the rows which fulfill the rule and replicate them as requested. Finally, the additional rows are appended to the original data set `DT`:

```
rbindlist(
  c(list(DT), 
    unlist(
      lapply(seq_len(nrow(rows_to_repeat)), function(.i) 
        replicate(rows_to_repeat[.i, n_rep], 
                  DT[eval(parse(text = rows_to_repeat[.i, rule]))], 
                  simplify = FALSE)),
      recursive = FALSE)))
```

> ```
>     Age Sex Height Weight  Status       obesity
>  1:  17   m    5.6   36.3  single        Normal
>  2:  30   f    4.5   80.5 married      Abnormal
>  3:  31   f    5.5   60.7  single        Normal
>  4:  35   m    4.9  110.9  single Very Abnormal
>  5:  30   f    4.5   80.5 married      Abnormal
>  6:  30   f    4.5   80.5 married      Abnormal
>  7:  30   f    4.5   80.5 married      Abnormal
>  8:  30   f    4.5   80.5 married      Abnormal
>  9:  30   f    4.5   80.5 married      Abnormal
> 10:  35   m    4.9  110.9  single Very Abnormal
> 11:  35   m    4.9  110.9  single Very Abnormal
> 12:  35   m    4.9  110.9  single Very Abnormal
> 13:  35   m    4.9  110.9  single Very Abnormal
> 14:  35   m    4.9  110.9  single Very Abnormal
> 15:  35   m    4.9  110.9  single Very Abnormal
> 16:  31   f    5.5   60.7  single        Normal
> 17:  35   m    4.9  110.9  single Very Abnormal
> 18:  31   f    5.5   60.7  single        Normal
> 19:  35   m    4.9  110.9  single Very Abnormal
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- readr::read_table(
  "Age    Sex    Height    Weight   Status    obesity  
  17      m      5.6      36.3     single    Normal  
  30      f      4.5      80.5     married   Abnormal
  31      f      5.5      60.7     single    Normal
  35      m      4.9      110.9    single    Very Abnormal"
)
setDT(DT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
 df %>%
   filter(grepl('Abnormal',obesity)) %>%
   slice(rep(1:n(), each=5)) %>%
   rbind(df)
```

which gives (5 repetitions for each row):

```
   Age Sex Height  Status       obesity
1   30   f   80.5 married      Abnormal
2   30   f   80.5 married      Abnormal
3   30   f   80.5 married      Abnormal
4   30   f   80.5 married      Abnormal
5   30   f   80.5 married      Abnormal
6   35   m  110.9  single Very Abnormal
7   35   m  110.9  single Very Abnormal
8   35   m  110.9  single Very Abnormal
9   35   m  110.9  single Very Abnormal
10  35   m  110.9  single Very Abnormal
11  17   m   36.3  single        Normal
12  30   f   80.5 married      Abnormal
13  31   f   60.7  single        Normal
14  35   m  110.9  single Very Abnormal
```

Comment: @ Aramis7. Thanks. But using `View(df)` is not showing the whole replicated records.

Comment: did you save the output to `df` first? try replacing `%>%` with `%<>%` maybe?